# Run additional EXE from 2012 InstallShield

Tags: c#, exe, installshield

I have created an installshield project using the Limited edition 2012 of InstallShield.

My application uses the Microsoft Agent 2.0 control in some places. So my question would be :

**How do i run the Agent installer from my install wizard?** Either before the main app is installed or after...

Also, i have set a prerequisite on the setup project to include .NET 4.5 and the installer to require .NET 4.5...but if i uninstall .NET and run my setup, it simply says i need the .NET Framework, rather than installing it...any ideas?

Comment: an answer would be nice :D

Answer (score 0):

Add a prerequisite installer for agent. And keep the one for.net, it shouldn't install if it is already present. If you don't need .net then look for a install condition that is requiring it.